# Why is DateTime() not working in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datetime, datepicker

I have time from date picker that looks like this: 2017-12-10T14:40:18.492Z. I tried to use the code below in Laravel to convert it to MySQL date format but it is throwing up error saying that 
(1/1) FatalThrowableError
Class 'iirs_demo\Http\Controllers\DateTime' not found

```
<?php $date = new DateTime('2000-01-01'); echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>
```

Please, how do I resolve it?

Thanks.

Comment: how is this laravel?

Answer (score 7):

PHP is not finding the correct path. For this, use a `\` before the function:

```
<?php $date = new \DateTime('2000-01-01'); echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>
```

Comment: I'm getting this: "2017-12-10 21:54:52.389000", "timezone_type": 2, "timezone": "Z" How can I make it look like MySQL date format? @Laerte

Comment: This code is correct. You should get MySQL format.